# How to use the uicontrolstate function in the table view cell image?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4

Am using the uiimageview in the CellForRowAtIndext as like below

```
int k=5;
for(int i=1; i<=3;i++) {

    btn_img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(k,50,90, 40)];
    btn_img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[image_array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    btn_img.tag=i;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn_img];
    k=k+95;
    [btn_img release];
```

}

through this I can able to display images 3 in a row.
but each image are differ. If particular image is clicked. How can I identify that particular image id?

```
for(int i=0; i<=2;i++) { 
if (m<[image_array1 count]) { 
    btn_img=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(k,5,90, 50)]; 
    UIImage *buttonImage= [UIImage imageNamed:[image_array1 objectAtIndex:m]]; 
    [btn_img setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    btn_img.tag=i; 
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap_gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)]; 
    [tap_gr setNumberOfTapsRequired:1]; 
    [btn_img addGestureRecognizer:tap_gr]; 
    [tap_gr release]; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn_img]; 
    k=k+95; 
    [btn_img release]; 
    m++; 
}
}
```

I confused how to write in the didselectrowatindexpath.

Thanks!

Senthilkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Add the tap gesture recognizer to `btn_img` as follows.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap_gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[tap_gr setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[btn_img addGestureRecognizer:tap_gr];
[tap_gr release];
```

In your handle tap method, you can access the `tag` of the image view that is tapped, and do the necessary action.

```
- (void)handleTap:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Tapped ImageView tag : %d", [sender tag]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I try this way images display correctly but i try to scroll the table cell upside the images as hide. what i do?

Comment: @Senthilkumar: Sorry I dont understand you clearly. Can you elaborate. post some code.

Comment: for(int i=0; i<=2;i++) { 
  if (m<[image_array1 count]) {
  btn_img=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(k,5,90, 50)];
  UIImage *buttonImage= [UIImage imageNamed:[image_array1 objectAtIndex:m]];
  [btn_img setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
  btn_img.tag=i;
  
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap_gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
  [tap_gr setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [btn_img addGestureRecognizer:tap_gr];
  [tap_gr release];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:btn_img];
  k=k+95;
  [btn_img release];
  m++;
  }

Comment: this code is used in the cellforrowatindexpath. while run the app at he initial stage all images displayed but i try to scroll the cell upwards the button to be hide.

Comment: Default coding of celforrowatidenxpath and then befor for loop k=5; this coding only i add.

Comment: @Senthilkumar: post your full cellForRowAtIndexPath: code. Post it in your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICustomButtons for that purpose.Set the background image of buttons,set the id of buttons while assigning image to a particular button.So when a particular button is tapped,the id of that button can be identified.Write a method to perform the required operations.

Cheers

Comment: Hai Aditya am also used uibutton. But am not able to select that particular image. it select all images in that row. so please give idea with coding for how to select the particular image in a cell?